# Is some sweep beneficial with taper?

Tags: wing, wing-sweep, canard

I'm developing a canard glider which requires some taper for the canard to stall first. I understand that sweep is typically only for aircraft in a compressible airflow (M >= 0.3), but is there any benefit to having sweep such that the trailing edge is straight?[image]